# How can i match String value to Arraylist<Delivery.Address> value in Java?

Tags: java

How can I match String value to `ArrayList<DeliveryArea.Address>` value in Java?

I have an `ArrayList<DeliveryArea.Address>` and `String` value. I fetched both the value. But when I was apply condition value are not match.

`DeliveryArea` class:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class DeliveryArea {
    @SerializedName("DeliveryAreaResult")

    public List<Address> address;

    public class Address{

        @SerializedName("restaurant_delivery_area")
        public String name;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%s ", name);
        }

    }
}
```

Condition is

```
String uservalue = locality.getText().toString();
Log.i("ll", uservalue);

for (int c = 0; c < ff.size(); c++) {
    Log.i("ll", "" + ff.get(c));
    if(uservalue.equals(ff.get(c))) {
        System.out.println("Sucess");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Sucessq");
    }
}
```

Fetch `ArrayList` value is...

```
ff = new ArrayList<DeliveryArea.Address>();
ff = deliveryarea.address;
Log.i("sunder123ererrer",""+ff);
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are having issue ? Minimalistic code please, also, please understand you cannot do a direct comparison of different types in java, you will need to come up with a way to convert them to a common type

Comment: This the codition       String uservalue=locality.getText().toString();
               Log.i("ll", uservalue);
               
               for (int c = 0; c<ff.size(); c++) {
                Log.i("ll", ""+ff.get(c));
                if(uservalue.equals(ff.get(c)))
             {
              System.out.println("Sucess");
             }
             
             else{
              System.out.println("Sucessq");
             }

Comment: Please add that to the question, and explain clearly the types of each variable, from your question code, and the code you put in comment, there is no way others can make out the type of the variables, to fint out what issue you are getting

Answer (score 2):

When you are doing a check like -

```
uservalue.equals(ff.get(c))
```

Where uservalue is type `String` and `ff.get(c)` returns type `Address` object. They would not be equal , since they are objects of different types. Also, java will not call `toString()` automatically.

You will have to manually call name member variable of the `ff.get(c)` object for the comparison to work , if `uservalue` also contains the same `name` .

```
if(uservalue.equals(ff.get(c).name))
```

Also, automatic calls to `toString()` function for an object, only occur when you are passing the function as a parameter to another function (or assigning it to a variable) where it the type of the variable is `String` .

In case of `.equals()` function , the parameter that it accepts is of type - `Object` - hence the automatic call to `toString()` does not happen. ([Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)))

Comment: Why would you check for equality with the result of the `toString` method of `Address` ? `uservalue.equals(ff.get(c).name)` still works if you change the `toString` method.

Comment: Yea it does in his particular case, but in general when you are comparing two different types of object with one being string, and the other being some other custom object (though such cases should not occur), I think its preferable to compare using `toString` method, rather than use a member variable.

Comment: @sunder sharma what does `uservalue` contain, should it contain the same value as `Address.toString()` ?

Comment: @AnandSKumar: He wants to check if the `name` of the `Address` is equal to a `String` value. You should never compare a `String` with an object (in this case `Address`).

Comment: @AnandSKumar thnku sir for  your suggestion but your answer is wrong.By the help of  your answer i sloved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you hold in `uservalue`

depending the value of `uservalue`:
you should change the following line:
 `if(uservalue.equals(ff.get(c)))` 
to

```
if(uservalue.equals(ff.get(c).name))
```

or

```
if(uservalue.equals(ff.get(c).toString()))
```